# How do I make small local commits with TFS?

Tags: tfs

I'm in a company now that forces TFS upon us. I have used Git all my life, and I am struggling to find some features I am used to in TFS. For example, I'd like to make small commits locally and push them up later together. This way I can keep track of my changes and roll back if I ever need to. Is there a way to do this in TFS?

Comment: There's something called Shelveset, which is like a personal, global way to commit branches. Quite horrible, but the best TFS has to offer in this regard. Better have a look at [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs).

Comment: There are a few git-TVFC bridges available. I'm not sure if they're as robust as the Subversion bridge, but at least you should be able to use git locally like you're used to.

Comment: @Wilbert: I recently transitioned from TFS to Git, and I find Git quite horrible. The things I am missing the most in Gist from TFS are Shelveset and Suspend Work.

Comment: @sergiol Since git branches are very lightweight, I generally just store whatever I would put in a shelve-set on a branch locally. There's also git-worktree which allows you to have different branches checked out at the same time, which might make sense if you only have a single master repository and no forks.

Comment: @Wilbert: Shelveset and Suspend Work are features where things will be saved in the remote repository. And the point is to have a backup of the code on a place that is not my machine.

Comment: @sergiol Even better, then you can just use the normal fork workflow and put all your personal branches on your fork. Pull request to the authoritative repo's master branch when a feature is done.

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is called "shelvesets" within TFS.

This link explains how to create one:

- [MSDN on how to create a shelveset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**To shelve folders and files from Solution Explorer**

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click, and then click Shelve Pending Changes.
2. In the Shelve - Source Files dialog box, type the shelveset name (for example, shelvetest) in the Shelveset name box.
3. The Shelve - Source Files dialog box includes two options:

   - Preserve pending change locally
   - By default, this option is selected. When this option is selected, the changes you made to the files or folders in your local workspace are preserved.
   - Evaluate Policies and check-in notes before shelving
   - When this option is selected, all check-in policies are evaluated before the shelveset is created. For more information, see Set and Enforce Quality Gates.
4. In the Comment box, type Testing my shelveset, and then click Shelve.

   The files and folders are copied to the version control server and are available for other team members to unshelve.

---

And this link provides some background about using shelvesets:

- [MSDN on reasons to use a shelveset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx)

For a variety of reasons, sometimes you need to set aside some or all of your work in progress. Shelvesets are useful when you want to stop work for:

- **Interruption:** You have pending changes that are not ready for check in, but you need to work on a different task.
- **Collaboration:** You have pending changes that are not ready for check in but you need to share them with another team member.
- **Code Review:** You want another team member to perform a code review of your pending changes.
- **Private Build:** Before you check in your changes, you can use your automated build system to build and test your code.
- **Backup:** You have work in progress that you cannot finish now so you want a backup copy that is stored on your server and available to other team members who might need to access it.
- **Handoff:** You have work in progress that you want to hand off to another team member.